# Manage CRUD operations for Hierarchical data (tree structure) with SonataAdminBundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I had implemented SonataAdminBundle to control CRUD operations. Now i want to use it for managing hierarchical data (tree structure) for Category section. 
I got one solution at - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418196/Editing-Tree-Structures-in-Symfony to manage tree structure, but its just updating parent field in database (Also i am not able to display listing with hierarchy levels).

Is it possible to update all other fields such as lft, rgt, level etc. So every insert/update operation will update these fields.

Below is CategoryAdmin code using which i am able to add category by selecting parent one which works fine but not updating values for fields lft, rgt, level.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery;

class CategoryAdmin extends Admin
{   
    protected $maxPerPage = 2500;
    protected $maxPageLinks = 2500;

    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $em = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('AppBundle\Entity\Category');

       $queryBuilder = $em
           ->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->select('c')
           ->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')
           ->where('c.parent IS NOT NULL');

        $query = new ProxyQuery($queryBuilder);
        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('up', 'text', array('template' => 'AppBundle:admin:field_tree_up.html.twig', 'label'=>' '))
            ->add('down', 'text', array('template' => 'AppBundle:admin:field_tree_down.html.twig', 'label'=>' '))
            ->addIdentifier('name', null, array('sortable'=>false, 'label'=>'Category Title'))
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array()
                ), 'label'=> 'Actions'
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('Category')
            ->add('parent', 'entity', array(
                                      'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
                                      'label' => 'Parent',
                                      'required'=>true,
                                      'query_builder' => function($er) use ($id) {
                                            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c');

                                            $qb
                                                ->orderBy('c.root, c.lft', 'ASC');
                                            return $qb;
                                        }
                ))
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Title'))
        ->end()
        ;
    }
}
```